# How can I implement table footer of ng2-smart-table?

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I’m now implementing ng2-smart-table in my application. I want to display table footer below the table for additional information such as Sum Amount, Discount Amount and so on.
[image]

This is my code in typescript file

```
settings = {
    columns: {
      seq: {
        title: '#',
        editable: false,
        width: '10%'
      },
      productName: {
        title: 'Product Name',
        editable: false
      },
      qty: {
        title: 'Qty.',
        width: '10%'
      },
      uom: {
        title: 'Uom',
        width: '10%'
      },
      price: {
        title: 'Price',
        valuePrepareFunction: (price) => {
          var formatted = this.thbCurrencyPipe.transform(price, 2);
          return formatted;
        }
      },
      discount: {
        title: 'Disc.'
      },
      amount: {
        title: 'Amount'
      }
    }
  };
```

And I load data in `ngOnInit()` method

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._utilityService.LoadPosDummyData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.datas = data;
    });
  }
```

This is `ng2-smart-table` tag I used in Html

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="datas"></ng2-smart-table>
```

Comment: create a separate component for it

Comment: It depends on how you are storing the data, but the `reduce` function would probably be along the lines of what you want. If you provide some code I can better help/explain.

Comment: @MichaelSolati I've already added code snippet above, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separated component to show the Sum information you want, listen to data updates on the main table and update the footer component.

On your html

```
<ng2-smart-table #grid
```

On your component

```
@ViewChild('grid')
table;
```

Subscribe for the on changed source observable from the smart-table

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.table.grid.source.onChangedSource.subscribe(() => {
        // update other component with the SUM
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks to @hamilton.lima for your answer, Now I've created another section as a footer to summarize information.

Comment: I have tried as like above but it didn't work for me.Showing error in this.table.grid.source grid of undefined.Could you please update your code with some clear example.